# Can't start VM in Virtualbox after update

Tags: virtualbox

I just updated virtualbox to the latest 4.1.16 r78094 and realized that I can no longer start my virtual machines.

If I start a VM, the error displayed is:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Historical Image.

Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_NO_MEMORY).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}
```

I have 8GB RAM in my VM host which is running OSX 10.6 of which I have over 4GBs free. Does anyone know how I can get my VMs working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a well known issue and at the moment you have two options:

- install new version from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.1.18/VirtualBox-4.1.18-78361-OSX.dmg
- downgrade your version to previous one: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_1